# How to create a png in the resource folder of a jar/war?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a method that creates a png file and then writes an image to it, however, this method works when I run the project in the IDE and fails to execute it .war, probably because of the file path.
I tried several ways that I found searching but did not succeed. Is there a way to create this png file in the resource folder so that it works in the IDE and .war?

My code that does not work in .war:

```
public File createPng(String name) throws Exception {
    String signatureName = "signature"+name+".png";

    File result = new File("src/main/resources/static/signature/"+ signatureName);
    result.createNewFile();

    ImageIO.write(bfImagem, "png", result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create it in the `resources/` folder? It doesn't really make sense when you're executing your `war` on an application server, where the `resources/` folder is but an entry of the `war` archive, which is not supposed to be modified by the application server.

Comment: When you run in IDE new File("src/main/resources/static/signature/ will be resolved with respect to your current working directory that is your Project Directory. But when running in an application server the current working directory is deployment folder, and most likely there isnt a src/main/resources/static/signature subfolders.

Comment: It was not me who wrote the method !! I need only create a png and 'write' the image on it because this image will be sent by email, by me, this file can be a temporary one and disappear after sending email, but I need the file to be created and used within .war or IDE.

Comment: If a temporary file is acceptable, [create a temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).  You often cannot change the contents of a .jar or .war at runtime, and even if you find that you can, there is no guarantee the class loader would be aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as suggested and I used temp file and it worked.

The code looks like this:

```
public File createPng(String name) throws Exception {
    String nameFile = "file_"+name.trim();
    String suffix = "png";        
    
    result = File.createTempFile(nameFile, suffix);

    ImageIO.write(bfImagem, "png", result);

    return result;
}
```